# How to reset position of ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview

In my program can I move image across screen? Sometimes I am loosing it from site and cannot find it. I wish to add function which will place imag on original position. 
My own aproach wich does not work ([and related question to it to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694347/is-there-history-or-matrix-translation)):

```
ImageView iv = current;
Matrix matrix = iv.getImageMatrix;
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);
int a = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
int b = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
matrix.postTranslate(-a,-b);
iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

**EDIT:** Latest code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.UILApplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageShowActivity extends Activity {
    int p = 0;
    Activity app;
    ImageAdapterr ia;
    ImageView imView;
    int imgPos = 0;
    Bitmap bm = null;
    int geg = 90;
    public int width = 0;
    public int hight = 0;
    Gallery gallery;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix shift = new Matrix();
    private int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mLastTouchX = 0;
    private float mLastTouchY = 0;
    private float mPosX = 0;
    private float mPosY = 0;
    ImageView current;
    public List<ImageView> images;
    public int reset = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> map = new HashMap<Integer, Bitmap>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_show);
        app = this;
        images = new ArrayList<ImageView>(
                UILApplication.photo_buffer_big.size());
        Log.d("images", UILApplication.photo_buffer_big.size() + "");
        Log.d("images", images.size() + "");
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        // EDGES ARE INVISIBLE

        gallery.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

        ia = new ImageAdapterr(this);

        gallery.setAdapter(ia);
        final int length = UILApplication.photo_buffer_big.size();
        Button back_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.analitics_back_btn);
        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        final TextView img_counter_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.img_counter);
        img_counter_tv.setText(p + 1 + "/" + length);
        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (p < length - 1) {
                    p++;
                } else {
                    p = 0;
                }
                gallery.setSelection(p, true);
                img_counter_tv.setText(p + 1 + "/" + length);
            }
        });

        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (p == 0) {
                    p = length - 1;
                } else {
                    p--;
                }
                gallery.setSelection(p, true);
                img_counter_tv.setText(p + 1 + "/" + length);

            }
        });


    }

    public void rotateS(View v) {
        ImageView iv = current;
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(geg);
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
                b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
    }

    public void extendS(View v) {

        reset = 1;
        Log.d("restart", "yes");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                View viewToUpdate = gallery.getChildAt(p - gallery.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                viewToUpdate.invalidate();
//              ia.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });



    }

    public static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap photo, float x, float y) {

        try {
            // get current bitmap width and height
            int width = photo.getWidth();
            int height = photo.getHeight();

            // determine how much to scale
            float scaleWidth = x / width;
            float scaleHeight = y / height;
            Log.d("aspect3", "w: " + scaleWidth + " h: " + scaleHeight);
            // create the matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bitmap
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            // recreate the new bitmap
            Bitmap resizebitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, width,
                    height, matrix, false);
            return resizebitmap;

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.gc();
        }
        return null;
    }

    class ImageAdapterr extends BaseAdapter {

        /** The parent context */
        private Context myContext;

        /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
        public ImageAdapterr(Context c) {
            this.myContext = c;
        }
        Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
        /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
        public int getCount() {
            return UILApplication.photo_buffer_big.size();
        }

        /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new ImageView to be displayed, depending on the position
         * passed.
         */


        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView imView = new ImageView(this.myContext);
            current = imView;
            imgPos = position;
            if (bm==null){
            AsyncLoad imLoad = new AsyncLoad();
            imLoad.execute();
            try {
                bm = imLoad.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            if (bm != null) {
                imView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } else if (bm == null) {
                imView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
            }
            /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
            imView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
            imView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            imView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                private static final String TAG = "Touch";
                // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image


                PointF start = new PointF();
                public PointF mid = new PointF();

                // We can be in one of these 3 states
                public static final int NONE = 0;
                public static final int DRAG = 1;
                public static final int ZOOM = 2;
                public int mode = NONE;

                float oldDist;

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {

                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(mid, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        if (mode == DRAG) {

                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                    event.getY() - start.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {

                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {

                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                        mode = NONE;
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                        break;
                    }

                    // Perform the transformation
                    Log.d("point",
                            (event.getX() - start.x) + " "
                                    + (event.getY() - start.y));
                    // Log.d("point",start.x +" "+start.y);
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float a = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float b = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    Log.d("touch matrix", values[Matrix.MPERSP_0] + " "
                            + values[Matrix.MPERSP_1] + " "
                            + values[Matrix.MPERSP_2]);
                    Log.d("touch matrix scale", values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] + " "
                            + values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
                    Log.d("touch matrix scew", values[Matrix.MSKEW_X] + " "
                            + values[Matrix.MSKEW_Y]);
                    Log.d("touch matrix trans", values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + " "
                            + values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
                    if (reset == 1) {
                        matrix.reset();
                        savedMatrix.reset();
                    }

                    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    reset = 0;
                    // images.set(position, view);
                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                }

                private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                }

                private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {

                    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
                }

            });

            return imView;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views depending on the
         * 'offset' to the center.
         */
        public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
            return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float) Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
        }
    }

    class AsyncLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(app);
            pd.setOwnerActivity(app);
            pd.setTitle("Идет загрузка...");
            pd.setCancelable(true);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                /*
                 * Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it.
                 */
                URL aURL = new URL(UILApplication.photo_buffer_big.get(imgPos));
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                is.close();
                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                // imView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // imView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
                bm = null;
                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);
            }
            map.put(imgPos, bm);
            Log.d("map", map.size() + "");
            return bm;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap arg0) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

XML

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_tab_bg"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/analitics_back_btn"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/back_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_clk_selector"
            android:text="Назад" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_rotate"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/analitics_back_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_clk_selector"
            android:onClick="rotateS"
            android:text="Повернуть" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ex"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_rotate"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_clk_selector"
            android:onClick="extendS"
            android:text="рас" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_btn"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next_img_btn"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/img_counter"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next_btn"
            android:text="1/10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_counter"
            android:background="@drawable/back_img_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <Gallery
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/gallery"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:spacing="10dp"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** problem with new code - image is not rested after enlargeS was called. It is reseted after enlargeS call + tab on screen. Also image is partially reseted - it goes to original position and scale, but it goes to its original resolution. So usually i bacamos much smaller then screen, while i need it to fill screen.

Comment: Can you place the code where you move the image?

Comment: have you tried to reset the matrix to the identity matrix?

Comment: sure:) it moved imageview 1 pixel back)

Comment: "Sometimes I am loosing it from site and cannot find it.". You've got yourself a bit of a nasty design problem here. Can I humbly suggest a way to clear it up might be to do less in getView() - just make a relative layout that fills parent, then set your image inside that layout, centered, with the bounds of the view fitting the image, no snazzy scale type, and implement on that image (the view, that is, not the bitmap inside) some kind of drag and expand functionality solely using layout parameters for now (there are a few examples available).

Comment: I d like to see you suggestion

Comment: can you give link to examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code here below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.TOP);
layout.addView(imageView);
```

This will position the `ImageView` at the center of the `RelativeLayout` which contains it.

**EDIT**: see in the code above - I changed the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, because it is the `LinearLayout`, which contains the `RelativeLayout` in fact. Now it should work.

Comment: Why not? I don't thin kthat this will fix definatelly the image on the center. If your code for the "dragging" woks well, it shouldn't be interfered by and external position change.

Comment: i have error when implementing your solution. I show it in question body

Comment: I've saw it, paste the XML of those buttons and it's container. Thanks

Comment: Paste the imports at the beginning as well.

Comment: i comment layout.addView(imageView); because image view is a chiled of gallery

Comment: Then change `RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);` to `RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gal);`, uncomment `layout.addView(imageView);` import `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

Comment: It does not like to ad child to onother parent :)

Comment: Пиздец. How come it doesn't like it :) Does it give you and error or something?

Comment: :))) Change `ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);` to `imageView = new ImageView(this);` - last resort :) I think this one will fix this. Надеюсь ..

Comment: Then try replacing `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` with `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);`. Then replace `imageView = new ImageView(this);` with `imageView = new ImageView(DestinationContext); // Or getBaseContext(), or MainActivity.this`. I really messed this up, but that's because I don't have a place to test this code :( Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your code to set the image view wherever you want on the screen,

```
iconSMS.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_smsmms);      
        LayoutParams paramsIconSMS = new LayoutParams(iconwidth,iconheight);
        iconwidthspacing=(int)Math.round(((float)width/480)*(float)45);
        iconheightspacing=(int)Math.round(((float)height/800)*(float)520);
        paramsIconSMS.setMargins(iconwidthspacing, iconheightspacing, 0, 0);
        iconSMS.setId(204);
        iconSMS.setLayoutParams(paramsIconSMS);
```

Here,

```
iconwidth=(int)Math.round(width*iconwidthf);
        iconheight=(int)Math.round(height*iconheightf);
```

and width and height variables are,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

by width and height you are getting the screen size of your phone in pixels.