# How to implement getMatrix()

Tags: android, matrix

On Android API 11 there is method View.getMatrix. however there is no shuch method for android API 8. How can I provide simmilar functionality?

```
        gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                geg = 90;

//              shift=v.getMatrix();
                current = (ImageView) v;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
```

In galleryview i can drag image across and behind screen, but after zooming image can appear so afar avay from screen so you do not know where to drag it back. So i want to make buttom to set it to original possition.

Comment: This is a good question, but to answer in the best possible way, please tell us a bit about what you're trying to achieve! Are you hoping to transform the view? Or perhaps just use that information in a different way?

Comment: As I understand View.getMatrix() keeps information about view transformation. Thus I believe if I will be able to get this matrix and reset - I will recieve original view. The problem arrise from there  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676485/how-to-reset-position-of-imageview

Comment: This sounds like an interesting scenario. This *field* does not exist in API 8, it's not just a matter of not having getters. *But* I strongly suspect you don't want it anyway. What do you mean by "original view"? And, more crucially, could you please add to your question what **kind** of view, because most views concatenate extra matrices onto draw canvases. For example, if it's an image view, you need a completely different solution.

Comment: I thought i need imageview.getImageMatrix, but it is empty

Comment: I've just posted an answer. Why do you need getImageMatrix? What are you trying to do? Thanks. Tom.

Comment: In galleryview i can drag image across and behind screen, but after zooming image can appear so afar avay from screen so you do not know where to drag it back. So i want to make buttom to set it to original possition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method in API 11 gets a field `TransformationInfo mTransformationInfo;` in View: see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/View.java#View.0mTransformationInfo). Sadly, in [API 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/View.java), it's not just a matter of the getters not being available, the field simply isn't used.

So there is no implementation possibility.

But you probably didn't want to do that anyway:

1. You're not really meant to use the api like this. Modifying by calling `getMatrix()` would circumvent a whole lotta calls that need to be made. Look at the source for `setPivotX(float pivotX)` [for example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setPivotX%28float%29). Use these accessory calls. They're you're friend! *Don't* think- I've got a view that's like this, how do I apply the inverse transformation to it to go back to where I was. *Do* think, after this transformation, I'm going to set an identity matrix on everything so that the view isn't transformed. Then you don't need to do any work!
2. Most Android views have their own matrices that are concatenated onto the `Canvas` in an overriden `Draw` call. So trying to get hold of something in `View` isn't going to help you. Say, for example, you wanted to reset the cropping on an `ImageView`. Well, `getMatrix()` of View simply won't tell you anything about that transform.
3. Why do you want to do this? What's the background here? Are you wanting to reset an animation? In that case, you're interested in the **layout** properties, not the transformations performed on the canvas!

By all means edit your question to include these considerations, and then it'd be lovely to come to a wider solution.

Comment: Sorry, for confussion. I thought pivot manipulation will help me, but it does not.

Comment: No! I'm trying to tell you you *don't* need these things.

Comment: We'd love to help you on SO, but the rules say we have to answer specific questions, and your question isn't going to help you! :( . Tell you what, why don't you post a *new* question, stating precisely what you need, and then someone might be able to answer it!

Comment: Oh I really missanderstand you, sorry

Comment: (In the mean time, you'll notice I've answered your question, so unless you have any specific points on which is it false, please mark it as so).

Comment: I really wish to find unswer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676485/how-to-reset-position-of-imageview?noredirect=1#comment25872623_17676485 :)